# SIP trunking and call routing in Kamailio

Tags: sip-server, kamailio, freepbx

I was using freepbx, but because of some limits I installed kamailio on another machine.
I want to have a route for outgoing calls to NGN(was peer friend siptrunk in freepbx), which handles call setups started from extensions registered on kamailio.
and another route which send incoming calls to a freepbx ivr.
how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamailio controlled via config file. You can add if operator based on any info you want(source ip, destination number etc etc ) and choose for each own route.

You also can use already writed module like carrierroute https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/3.0.x/modules/carrierroute.html, which use prefix table for selection.